# How to get "HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY" with django python

Tags: python, django, http

I'm unable to get HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY from http meta data.
I want to get country code.

```
def register(request):
    country_code = request.META.get('HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY', 'N/A').strip()
    print("THIs is ",country_code)
```

this prints --> **N/A**

Comment: Are your requests coming from CloudFlare?

Comment: No, i dont know what cloudflare is

Comment: That header is present only for Cloud Flare requests if you have IP Geolocation enabled. Of course you can't get that header on localhost.

Comment: So what can I do, Shoud i create an account on cloud flare ?

Comment: Yes, but it will only work on an actual server. Not on localhost.

Comment: Oh okay, Will heruko work for it?

Comment: You can send a get request to `http://api.ipify.org/?format=json` and it will return the user's ip address then use the ip to send a get request to `https://iplist.cc/api/<ip_addr>` and that will give you the country code.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I appreciate for giving me your time.

Comment: You can use a cloudflare tunnel to get this working in your local. Check out - https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/how-to/preview-with-cloudflare-tunnel and https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-Configuring-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation